# Error zipping all files in a directory

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm having trouble moving all the files in the directory into a zip file. Below is my code. When I run the code, no zip file is created. What am I doing wrong?

```
$dir = "archive";
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zipfile = "./test.zip";


$zip->open($zipfile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {

$zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Have u tried printing out the file names? print_r($file) within the loop. I think that you have to prepend the directory to the file names.

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file.

Comment: @LauriOrgla Thank you for the suggestion. I tried prepending the directory to the file names, and the zip file was created after I ran it again. The issue was the prepending.